# Connection to https://mail.google.com refused, apache httpclient

Tags: java, apache, https, httpclient

I can download files like that:

If url is , for instance http:/b.net/Doc1.pdf it downloads very well, but if it is, for example "https:/mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=e3036d4c0a&view=att&th=13c8b8af8687d931&attid=0.1&disp=safe&realattid=f_hckh9zby0&zw" (gmail attached pdf), it cant download. I have that error

***Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://mail.google.com refused***

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            long len = entity.getContentLength();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            File temp = File.createTempFile("Google", ".pdf", new File("/")); 
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;
            while ((n = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                output.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
            output.close();
        }
```

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://mail.google.com refused

Comment: In addition I have proxy on my PC

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this like that "http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java"

I had proxy problems;